# How to search and remove some values from xml java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml `abc.xml`

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
   <soapenv:Header/>

   <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:SomeRq>

         <RqID>?</RqID>

         <MsgRqHdr>
         ....
      </mes:SomeRq>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there a way i can search `mes:`, from this xml and replace it with `ins:`

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void findreplcae(String strFilePath) throws IOException {
    String currentString = "mes:";
    String changedString = "ins:";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strFilePath));

    StringBuffer currentLine = new StringBuffer();
    String currentLineIn;
    while ((currentLineIn = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(currentLineIn);
        boolean bool = false;
        String trimmedLine = currentLineIn.trim();
        System.out.println(trimmedLine);
        if (trimmedLine.contains(currentString)) {
            trimmedLine.replace(currentString, changedString);
            bool = true;
            if (bool != true) {
                currentLine = currentLine.append(currentLineIn + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strFilePath));
        writer.write(currentLine.toString());
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure there is. What have you tried so far? (Hint: people expect you to at least pretend that you want to work on the problem yourself; instead of just dropping your duties on other people).

Comment: #jagermeister i have updated the question and added my method

Comment: That is better; but still not a **good** question: now you are pasting code, but you don't tell us where your actual problem is. You should tell us what exactly happens when you run your code ... side note on code quality: findreplace is a really bad name for method (at least abide the java conventions for upper/lower case). Then: you are doing a lot of things within that method: better split that up into several methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

1. `trimmedLine.replace(currentString, changedString);`, the result is **returned**, so you have to store it somewhere. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))
2. What is this supposed to do?

   ```
   bool = true;
   if (bool != true) {
       currentLine = currentLine.append(currentLineIn + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
   }
   ```
3. Don't close the reader while reading in a loop.

If you want to overwrite the original file, this should do (although I am not sure, if you really want to trim the lines):

```
String currentString = "mes:";
String changedString = "ins:";
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(strFilePath));

    StringBuffer newContents = new StringBuffer();
    String currentLineIn = null;
    while ((currentLineIn = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String trimmedLine = currentLineIn.trim();
        if (trimmedLine.contains(currentString)) {
            newContents.append(trimmedLine.replace(currentString, changedString));
        }
        else {
            newContents.append(trimmedLine);
        }
        newContents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    reader.close();

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strFilePath));
    writer.write(newContents.toString());
    writer.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO handle it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not good idea to parse it as a text file. [DocumentBuilder.parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.io.File)) to parse the file, call `getDocumentElement()` and check for [`getPrefix`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getPrefix()). If it matches, replace with `setPrefix()`. Note you have to register prefix if not yet done already.

Check [this page](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) for tutorial.

Comment: Actually parsing the XML might not be desirable in all cases (in case of large files for example) and is also slower than a stream-based approach...